# Remove port from git URL on Bonobo Git Server

Tags: git, bonobo

My Bonobo git server are using custom port 9443, everything work properly until I published it behind NAT.
As you can see in my image, my git domain name is abc.com, but in git url it still add port 9443 into url, like abc.com:9443/123.git,that's wrong, so how can I remove this port in url? I think I should config something in git server?

[image: Wrong git url with port]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That seems similar to [Bonobo-Git-Server issue 294](https://github.com/jakubgarfield/Bonobo-Git-Server/issues/294) (which is about a similar mismatch)

> > This is probably because the port your server is listening on  does not match your router (#### in your example).
> >
> > **Bonobo picks up the port from the server it's running on**. In order to get them to match, you need to bind the Bonobo server/site to the same port and adjust the NAT on your router to route to the server also on the same port.

The solution was:

> Not sure why I didn't think about rebinding through IIS. I changed my port on the server and it is working properly now. Thanks!

Comment: You mean I have to change port on the server from 9443 to 80, but this server already have another site using port 80.

Comment: @TienDungTran that might be the issue in your case, since you cannot rebind through IIS.